# Replace a collection item using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects, .net-3.0

How do I find and replace a property using Linq in this specific scenario below:

```
public interface IPropertyBag { }
public class PropertyBag : IPropertyBag
{
    public Property[] Properties { get; set; }

    public Property this[string name]
    {
        get { return Properties.Where((e) => e.Name == name).Single(); }
        //TODO: Just copying values... Find out how to find the index and replace the value 
        set { Properties.Where((e) => e.Name == name).Single().Value = value.Value; }
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping out in advance.

Comment: What PropertyBag are you using? I don't think there's one in the .Net BCL.  I ask because the 'Properties' getter is probably the one doing the cloning, hence the reason why you can't do what you're trying to.

Comment: Jonathan, this my own custom PropertyBag class.. The code above works because I'm not replacing the entire item in the Property[] array.  The comment in the code illustrates that:
 //TODO: Just copying values... Find out how to find the index and replace the value

Comment: Just wondered why you did not use my LINQ-free IndexOf() solution ... now I know! I corrected my answer from instance to static method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not use LINQ because it will not improve the code because LINQ is designed to query collection and not to modify them. I suggest the following.

```
// Just realized that Array.IndexOf() is a static method unlike
// List.IndexOf() that is an instance method.
Int32 index = Array.IndexOf(this.Properties, name);

if (index != -1)
{
   this.Properties[index] = value;
}
else
{
   throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
}
```

[Why are Array.Sort() and Array.IndexOf() methods static?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/177259/why-are-array-sort-and-array-indexof-methods-static)

Further I suggest not to use an array. Consider using `IDictionary<String, Property>`. This simplifies the code to the following.

```
this.Properties[name] = value;
```

Note that neither solution is thread safe.

---

An ad hoc LINQ solution - you see, you should not use it because the whole array will be replaced with a new one.

```
this.Properties = Enumerable.Union(
   this.Properties.Where(p => p.Name != name),
   Enumerable.Repeat(value, 1)).
   ToArray();
```

Comment: "Do not use LINQ because it will not improve the code" without justification, this statement is useless

Comment: @danbruc: Unfortunately, using [I]Dicitonary is not option as it's not serializable... Have to leave it an array... yeah... IndexOf() seems a reasonable solution... but I was just hoping may be I was doing something wrong and there's indeed a way in Linq to do this...

Answer (score 0):

[note: this answer was due to a misunderstanding of the question - see the comments on this answer.  Apparently, I'm a little dense :(]
Is your 'Property' a class or a struct?

This test passes for me:

```
public class Property
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
public interface IPropertyBag { }
public class PropertyBag : IPropertyBag
{
    public Property[] Properties { get; set; }

    public Property this[string name]
    {
        get { return Properties.Where((e) => e.Name == name).Single(); }
        set { Properties.Where((e) => e.Name == name).Single().Value = value.Value; }
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestMethod1()
{
    var pb = new PropertyBag() { Properties = new Property[] { new Property { Name = "X", Value = "Y" } } };
    Assert.AreEqual("Y", pb["X"].Value);
    pb["X"] = new Property { Name = "X", Value = "Z" };
    Assert.AreEqual("Z", pb["X"].Value);
}
```

I have to wonder why the getter returns a 'Property' instead of whatever datatype .Value, but I'm still curious why you're seeing a different result than what I am.

Comment: It's a class... Comment re-pasted from above: The code above works because I'm not replacing the entire item in the Property[] array. The comment in the code illustrates that: //TODO: Just copying values... Find out how to find the index and replace the value

Comment: And hey Jonathan, I do appreciate you taking time out to help. Not an ungrateful moron, you see... :)

Comment: Could you paste in more of your code then?  The code I posted worked for me, and that's the only thing I can think of that would make it work like you describe.

Comment: The point is the following: "[...]Single().Value = value.Value;" just updates the value of the property but does not replace the property object in the array with the supplied one. This would require something like "[...]Single() = value;". Obvisiously this does not work - LINQ does not support

Comment: modifying collection. You have to build a new one and replace the old one with that - see the example in my answer - but this is not a smart solution.

Comment: Ah, I see what the real question is.  Yes, you cannot modify the collection with LINQ.  Language integrated **query**, not update.

Comment: I understand I can't use Linq as 'lvalue'... but can I at least get the index of the item in the collection?  If I could, I could modify the original collection using the index.  Thanks again danbruc & Jon.

Comment: Well, there's List<T>.FindIndex, but that's not available on Array (and I'm guessing the .ToList() would kind of defeat the purpose).  That said, you should be able to write a custom extension method to implement FindIndex on a array if you really want to.